# Harry Potter fanfic where Harry goes to live with Snape

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a fanfic where Dumbledore decided to send Harry 'live' with Snape after the events of the third or fourth book (if I'm not mistaken, the fourth).

At first Snape continues to see Harry as a child who has grown up being spoiled and worshiped all his life, but over time he realizes that he actually had a VERY abusive childhood with the Dursleys and changes his view of the boy.  I don't remember everything well, I know the story has more than 50 chapters and the snarry relationship gets very strong over time, Harry begins to consider Severus a father and Snape comes to see Harry as a son.  I think it was from Fanfiction.Net, not sure why I was reading a translation on Spirit.

I really love this fanfic and I really want to finish reading, since I couldn't because the translator deleted the profile and all the stories in it out of nowhere, without warning or something.

Comment: What language were you reading it in? Was it originally in English? We're all of the events in the break between the years? Were there any new characters or magic introduced?

Comment: Might be of help: https://www.fanfiction.net/community/Harry-Severus-Bonding/82350/ The common theme is Harry and Severus bonding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds very much like [A New Place To Stay](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/7104654/1/A-New-Place-To-Stay) by DebsTheSlytherinSnapefan.

> Harry is called up to Dumbledore's office at the end of his fourth year and told he is to go and live with Severus Snape. Severus does what no one else bothered to do― he takes care of Harry. Watch as Harry flourishes to all that he was meant to be: A Slytherin with a heart of a lion. No slash. Will Harry be able to beat Voldemort and save the people he loves? Read and find out.

At first Snape continues to see Harry as a child who has grown up being spoiled and worshiped all his life,

> Severus couldn't believe he had been talked into taking the spoiled, pampered Potter brat in over the summer. He had, of course, warned Dumbledore he wasn't going to baby the boy; Potter would learn to respect him one way or another.

but over time he realizes that he actually had a VERY abusive childhood with the Dursleys and changes his view of the boy.

> For the first time, Severus was seeing everything with a starling clarity. The boy's reaction to going home, having no decent clothes, the subservient attitude... Severus was still confused though; why had the boy hidden it? He had people who loved him; he would have been removed in seconds. Dumbledore under no circumstances would have allowed the boy to remain there if he'd known. Despite his confusion, Severus knew all too well why the boy wouldn't tell, and he felt his heart sink in fear and anger. He gripped the trunk, feeling ready to explode with all those warring emotions inside him. This was Lily's son. Lily's son... he wasn't supposed to be abused. It had never even occurred to Severus that Harry could be abused. He was loved by everyone; he was the last person you would expect to have to worry about.

Comment: Thank you very very very much. Oh really. I was very sad when the translator deleted everything out of nowhere and, as I had not kept the fanfic name, I could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

ok! so simply speaking: I think you are looking for this fanfiction by KurbyLane: "O Mine Enemy". It is a long fanfiction probably 50 chapters as you asked for.

Comment: aurora rosier has already indicated that [Turamarth's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/222142/122024) is correct, as denoted by the [green tick](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)  to the left of the answer and the [comment directly beneath it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221924/harry-potter-fanfic-where-harry-goes-to-live-with-snape/262551#comment613284_222142).